# Specific form in bison parser $<sval>$

Tags: c++, parsing, bison

I am writing a compiler and looking for examples I found the following code:

```
WHILE expression{
    string endLabel = createNewLabel();

    addToOutput("\tje" + getTypeSuffixFromSymbol($3) + "\t" +
    getAddressFromSymbol($3) + ",#0,#" + endLabel + "\n");

    $<sval>$ = strdup(endLabel.c_str());
}
```

I met with this first time. What is the purpose inside the variable `<sval>` or `<ival>`? I only use `$$`, `$1`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bison extension to the capabilities of yacc that allows access to any of the members of yytype. You can read about it here: [Action Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Action-Types.html#Action-Types)

Comment: Its actually part of normal yacc, not a bison extension.